# what is the probability that in a random group of seven people two were born on Monday and two on Sunday?

Tags: probability

If people can be born with the same probability any day of the week, what is the probability that in a random group of seven people two were born on Monday and two on Sunday?
My analysis: 
7 people can be born in 7^7 ways.
7 people can be shuffled in 7! Ways.
4 people occupy two days and the 3 remaining people occupy the 5 other days in 5^3
My analysis lead to the following solution: 7!*5^3/7^7
Is that correct?

Comment: Here I would guess a concept of partitions can be used. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to make an explanation for Phil:s answer.

1. We first choose the four people to have birthday on either sunday or monday. This can be done with something called "combinations" sometimes written nCr or $^nC_r$. 4 among 7 can be chosen in $^7C_4$ ways.
2. Then second factor is also an nCr, it is when whe calculate how many ways we can split those 4 people into groups of 2. One group for sunday and one for monday.
3. Last we have 3 people left and they can be put in any of the remaining free 5 days and that's where the $5^3=125$ comes from.

Comment: Thanks for explaining my answer. For your item 2, there are 4! ways to arrange 4 people, but because we have 2 pairs of the same day, we reduce this amount by dividing by 2! twice.

Comment: You are both amazing tutors. Thanks you a lot

Answer (score 1):

There are only $^7C_4\cdot \frac{4!}{2!\cdot 2!}\cdot 5^3$ ways to have four out of seven people with two birthdays on Monday and two on Tuesday.

$P(\text{mmtt}) = \frac{^7C_4\cdot \frac{4!}{2!\cdot 2!}\cdot 5^3}{7^7} = .03187$

Comment: Can you explain the procedure of the numerator. how did you  apply the multiplication rule?

Comment: This looks more reasonable, but maybe you can explain the different factors and why they are there to those who are new to combinatorics?

Comment: I thought 7! Was to shuffle the order of the 7 people but now you introduced the idea of 4!/2!*2! Can you please elaborate more on it?

Comment: Yes, $\frac{4!}{2!\cdot 2!}$ where $4!$ is the number of ways you can rearrange 4 people, but because there are 2 pairs having the same birth day, we need to reduce this by dividing by 2! twice.

Comment: @Rayen Sorry I wasn't around to answer your questions earlier, I hope you got your answers, let me know if you have other questions.

Answer (score 0):

First we choose 2 people among 7 that are born on monday and then we choose 2 people among 5 that are born on Sunday. So the number of good outcomes is $${7\choose 2}\cdot {5\choose 2} \cdot 5^3= 7\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 2\cdot 5^3 $$
so the probability you seek is $$P = {30\cdot 5^3\over 7^6}$$

Comment: However, I checked the solution and it was: 7!*5^3/24*7^7

Comment: If we ignore sunday and monday and 5 days left to distribute 3 people over, that's $5^3=125$ which is already bigger than $30$

Comment: @Rayen then why did you click accept answer?

Comment: Because in fact there is nothing wrong with your answer. Thanks you a lot ❤️